# Fabric.js : changing originX in ellipse changes left position

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am having a situation where I am drawing a ellipse in fabric.js from originX='right' and 
afterwards changing it to originX='left'.
What I see is after changing the originX to left and adjusting the left by the following calculation :

```
ellipse.left -= ellipse.width
```

I still see a difference in the left positions.

To explain it , I added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mRA8Z/62/) where I added a timeout of 3 seconds before changing the originX. So, please open the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mRA8Z/62/) and wait 3 seconds and see how the position changes which ideally shouldn't .
Any mistakes I am doing or any suggestions ?

Code :

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');
var ellipse = new fabric.Ellipse({
   left: 300,
   top: 10,
   rx: 145,
   ry: 65,
   strokeWidth: 4,
   stroke: 'blue',
   fill: '',
   originX: 'right',
   originY: 'top'
});
canvas.add(ellipse);
canvas.renderAll();
var log = document.getElementById('log');
log.innerHTML = ellipse.left;
//changing the origin
setTimeout(function() {
   ellipse.originX = 'left';
   ellipse.left -= ellipse.width;
   canvas.renderAll();
   log.innerHTML += ', ' + ellipse.left;
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, the ellipse­*'s* stroke has some width to it, hence, you would also need to exclude that, from ellipse­*'s* left position, like so ...

```
ellipse.left -= ellipse.width + ellipse.strokeWidth;
```

or

```
ellipse.left = ellipse.left - ellipse.width - ellipse.strokeWidth;
```

Here is the revised version of your code ...

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper', {
   isDrawingMode: false
});
var ellipse = new fabric.Ellipse({
   left: 300,
   top: 10,
   rx: 145,
   ry: 65,
   strokeWidth: 4,
   stroke: 'blue',
   fill: false,
   originX: 'right',
   originY: 'top'
});
canvas.add(ellipse);
canvas.renderAll();
var log = document.getElementById('log');
log.innerHTML = ellipse.left;

//changing the origin
setTimeout(function() {
   ellipse.originX = 'left';
   ellipse.left -= ellipse.width + ellipse.strokeWidth;
   canvas.renderAll();
   log.innerHTML += ', ' + ellipse.left;
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
<div id='log'></div>
```